# Dangers of storing rvalue references in templates

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, rvalue-reference

Consider following piece of code:

```
#include <functional>

template<class T>
class factory {
public:
    factory(T &&t) : t_(std::forward<T>(t)) {}

private:
    T &&t_;
};

template<class T>
factory<T> make_factory(T &&t) {
    return factory<T>(std::forward<T>(t));
}

int main(){
    int i = 3;
    auto bar = make_factory(i); //now it will store int &
    auto foo = make_factory(5); //now will store int &&
    return 0;
}
```

This is of course simplification of code but shows my general idea - I am considering storing references to rvalues. As far as I know in the first case the deduced type will be `int &` so the factory will be valid until leaving of the scope (due to reference collapsing). My questions are

1. Is the `foo` object causing undefined behaviour?
2. If not, for how long is the stored rvalue reference valid (I mean, what's its scope)?
3. Are there any caveats that I am missing?

EDIT:
I thought this is enough but I see I have to clarify. I want to achieve something like this:

```
template<class T>
class factory {
public:
    factory(T &&t) : t_(std::forward<T>(t)) {}

    auto make() const & {
        return wrap(t_);
    }

    auto make() && {
       return wrap(/*what here, move(t_), forward<T>(t_) ?*/);
    }
private:
    T t_;//or maybe T&& here?
};
```

I do not want to copy the member unless I **really** have to. I would like to do something like forwarding through the `factory` class.

Comment: Why are you considering doing this?

Comment: Its scope is just that expression.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I want to pass around large objects (containers to be preciese). I am experimenting with possible solutions to avoid copying as much as I can.

Comment: How about using pointers?

Comment: @NeilButterworth It is an option. As I said, I'm experimenting. I would not call it that way if knew what I was doing ;)

Answer (score 0):

Generally do this:

```
template<class T>
class factory {
public:
  factory(T &&t) : t_(std::forward<T>(t)) {}

private:
  T t_; // could be a lvalue ref
};
```

and it just works.  Really.  Yep, that case too.

Rvalues should not outlive their enclosing statement; so your make factory should not return a struct containing an rvalue ref.

Comment: Can I perfectly forward through object like this?

Comment: For r/lvalue this approach will have essentially different behavior. I'm afraid this will easily cause hidden bugs in the future.

Comment: @bartop Only use `std::forward` in a `&&` qualified method on member data, but sure.  Note `factory` will move-construct a copy.  There really isn't a safe way to avoid that, tho.

Comment: @lili it behaves like `auto&&` reference lifetime extension (or not).  You can also use `std::decay_t<T> t_;` for `auto` like behaviour.

Comment: @Yakk: There's a quirk here, that this instantiates `factory<int&>` or `factory<int&&>` rather than the expected `factory<int>`. That's worth calling out explicitly.

Comment: @Yakk It might be useful for immediate use, then go out of scope and throw away. Otherwise too error-prone.

Comment: @mooing yes, putting the decay in make, then perfect forwarding in factory ctor, can be a better plan.